# Data.slice is not a function Angular, trying to use parseint to convert strings into Date

Tags: angular, typescript, string, parseint

I want to convert the strings coming from my db into numbers and into dates.
In one instance they are coming as a string of miliseconds, and in the other as timestamps

[image]

I want to convert theese two into numbers and then into valid dates, the obj is build like this

```
timeInformacao: any = {
    score: 0,
    tempoLimite: "",
    tempoFinal: "",
    tempoLimiteDesafio: "",
    nomeDaEquipe: ""
  }
```

tempoFinal being the timestamp and tempoFinal being the string.

I've tried this construction:

```
    intializeResultado(): void {
    this.timeService.findAll().subscribe(times => {
      this.timeInformacao.tempoLimite = new Date(parseInt('', 10))
      this.todosTimes = times;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Time>(this.todosTimes)
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }
```

[image]

I want to handle this data before putting into a table, they coming like this will be confusing for the user.
How can I do this effectively?

Comment: the code you've shown does not show where/how you are using `slice`.  you probably want to update your question

Comment: Well that’s what’s weird about it, I didn’t use it. Nowhere in the code, there are no slice

Comment: based on the stack trace, the MatTable is expecting an array. have you logged out the `times` returned from your service call to confirm it is in fact an array?

Comment: @DanielFabre, use `MatTableDataSource<Time>` **not** convert to Time object each element from the array you received from your API, you should use map to convert the data you received in an array of Time objects and the use as dataSource the new TamTableDataSource

Comment: Well in this case Time ins't time, since is in portuguese, the person that did this code before put this, and it's confusing, but Time in this circustance is Team. I wanted to change the object names and some variables but don't have much time to do it so, and since the project has so many problems i think it would be hard to do it so

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that angular gives you...

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="tempoLimite">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Início </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let time"> {{time.tempoLimite | date :'short' }} </td>
      </ng-container>
```

But i still want to know how to do it using typescript, and why it keeps telling me about data.slice when I don't think i'm using it anywhere